# Expanded row getting collapsed on state update on react-table

Tags: reactjs, state, react-table, react-state, react-table-v6

How to stop the expanded React-Table row from collapsing on state change in-class component.

Please find the code link here https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-dubinsky-t0hcn?file=/src/nestead-table/index.js

on selecting or unselecting the checkbox (state update) the expanded row is getting collapsed please help me in solving this.

I have tried the below code. it's kept opening that nested row but inside the `subcomponent` nested table didn't show up (Please find below first image).... didn't work for me as it's a nested table. followed some documents https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useExpanded no luck!

here is the code which I have tried.

```
return (
    <ReactTable
      data={data}
      columns={columns}
      className='-striped -highlight'
      minRows={0}
      defaultPageSize={PAGE_SIZE}
      showPagination={data && data.length > PAGE_SIZE ? true : false}
      expanded={this.state.expanded}
      SubComponent={(row) => {
        // get current active key which needs to be expanded (triggered by clicking on a td element)
        const currentExpandedKey = currentExpandedKeys[row.index];
        let columnData = [];
        console.log('currentExpandedKey------------------', currentExpandedKey, this.state.expanded);
        return (
          <div className='react-nested-table-inner'>
            <h4 className='title'>
              {keyMaps[currentExpandedKey] || currentExpandedKey}
            </h4>
            {this.renderByData(
              row.original[currentExpandedKey],
              keyMaps,
              onCellDisplay
            )}
          </div>
        );
      }}
      // onExpandedChange={(newExpanded, index, event) => {console.log('onExpand', newExpanded, index, event)}}
      getTdProps={(state, rowInfo, column, instance) => {
        return {
          onClick: (e, handleOriginal) => {
            // used to identify which column is expanding
            if (column.expander) {
              const expanded = { ...this.state.expanded };
              expanded[rowInfo.viewIndex] = this.state.expanded[rowInfo.viewIndex] ? false : true;
              console.log('expanded-----', expanded)
              this.setState({ expanded: expanded });
              currentExpandedKeys[rowInfo.index] = column.id;
              console.log('currentExpandedKeys-----', currentExpandedKeys);
            }

            // IMPORTANT! React-Table uses onClick internally to trigger
            // events like expanding SubComponents and pivots.
            // By default a custom 'onClick' handler will override this functionality.
            // If you want to fire the original onClick handler, call the
            // 'handleOriginal' function.
            if (handleOriginal) {
              handleOriginal();
            }
          }
        };
      }}
    />
  );
```

**With the above code, I am getting below output.**
[image]

**looking for the following output.**
[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please include what you have tried doing already. Else, it shows a lack of effort from your side in asking the question. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ZameerHaque I have added what I have tried. please help me in solving this thank you.

Comment: No, you haven't, you linked to an external site.  You need to put your code in the question as text.  See [mre].

Answer (score 2):

in the useTable() table options, set *autoResetExpanded: false*. This fixed the problem for me.

You can also take a look at the documentation:

Info about the autoResetExpanded option: https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useExpanded

How do I stop my table state from automatically resetting when my data changes?: https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/faq#how-do-i-stop-my-table-state-from-automatically-resetting-when-my-data-changes

Answer (score 0):

I'm using session storage to cache the expanded row, therefore after update it stays open.

```
{
  JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(row.id) || "false") || row.isExpanded ? (
    <tr>
      <td colSpan={visibleColumns.length}>
        <table className="mx-auto my-2 w-[92%]">
          <thead className="bg-brand text-black text-lg">
            <tr>
              <th className="text-left">Name</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>Text</tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  ) : null;
}
```